# You can get unreviewable edits when rolling back

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits, rollbacks

I have this test answer:

[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/266266#266266)

So, I edited in spam, like people on SO.

Steps to repro:

1. [Put in crap as yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/266266/2).
2. [Someone below 2k suggest an edit to rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/41054). **MUST** rollback, not delete crap.

As of now, you cannot send in anything.

3. Now, a 2k+ user must click rollback from the revision history. **[MUST BE FROM HISTORY, OR COMMUNITY WILL REJECT IT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/41054)**

And now, we end up with this:

> This item is no longer reviewable.

However, its still pending.

Example:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/41056

Shouldn't Community reject it as conflict?

Comment: It isn't pending anymore... http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/303648/unibot?tab=activity - "rejected edit". Really, this is just a display bug... not that important since it takes a very certain chain of events to trigger it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The invalidated state is a built-in feature of the review system. When something happens to a post outside of review which somehow conflicts with the validity of that review task, the system immediately makes it unreviewable and will completely invalidate the task at some point in the near future (usually within 15 minutes).

This happens in *all* review queues, not just the suggested edits queue.